# Unresponsive trackpad, keyboard and Blinking cursor in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, keyboard, cursor, trackpad

My Ubuntu machine was working all right since a long time but today when I switched it on, it's greeted me oddly, it allowed me to open my user id but after that it's been (kinda) hijacked.

The mouse cursor is blinking continuously, the trackpad on my PC refuses to allow me to move the mouse, even the keyboard hasn't been responding and it's been like that since the last 15 minutes

I've been unsuccessful in even shutting off my laptop, and now the only option left is to cut the power supply.

How to fix this problem?

[image: The dialog boxes]

Comment: Are you able to use tty by Ctrl+Alt+F2 ?

Comment: Yes, I have logged in here but don't know how to use this

Comment: When I try to use any app, it says gtk-warning: cannot open display

Comment: Try to remember what you did yesterday. Probably something that required `sudo`.

Comment: No changes need info sudo were made, except I installed a few updates to the OS that were around 143 MB, @RegisteredUser

Comment: And just to assure you that it's **not** a hardware problem, my dual boot computer allows me to use both keyboard and mouse all right on Windows 7, also, after ctrl + alt + F2, my keyboard works and I can do stuff using cmd line, but when I do something like **gedit abc.txt** it fails to open gedit saying **gtk-warning: Cannot Open Display**

Comment: does keyboard works in Ctrl+ALt+F2 mode?

Comment: @user296776 , yes it does

Comment: install the common driver package and see. `sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-input-all`

Comment: Probably one of the updates made it unresponsive.

Comment: This is gettin even odd, I did sudo power off and now restarted it, and now it's got two dialogue boxes along with all previous problems saying "Failure to download extra data files" and "System program Problem Detected"

Comment: Even the fonts of the dialog boxes are changing continuously

Comment: @RegisteredUser doing that says dpkg was interrupted, you must manually run 'sudo dpkg --configure -a' to correct the problem

Comment: Ok never mind, I just did the sudo dpkg --configure -a and it's now working all right :)) and now, even this ass speaks the truth "Sorry, Ubuntu 14.04 has experienced an internal error"

Comment: I think you should write a answer for yourself and accept it so that this question will be considered "resolved". BTW the problem was that for some reason, the update process was interrupted which caused packages not to be configured. That's why `sudo dpkg configure -a` solved the problem.

Comment: Ok, sure will right it myself, @RegisteredUser

Comment: I've posted the answer, @RegisteredUser, please edit if you find any mistakes, and Thank you again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Somehow the updates had been interrupted, due to which the packages were not properly configured.

To fix this problem, login through tty(<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>)

and type the command,

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a
```

This should fix all problems.

Comment: Umm, is there something wrong with the answer, I mean, why was it downvoted ?

Answer (score 0):

```
# pip install xinput
```

Can u install this through command line and list all input device

```
# xinput list
```

if it disabled mean enable by like this

```
# xinput set-prop <device_id> "Device Enabled" 0
```

try this

Comment: Never mind, the problem was solved with assistance from @RegisteredUser

Comment: thats fine @Nib